# A riddle sure to stump you

Tags: riddle

What am I?

I'm not a thing you can see, nothing you can hold - but sometimes I'm part of what you say.

***Yes, you read it right, that's all there is... No, don't include this, it's just a note.***

Comment: Welcome to PSE. We hope you will continue to post questions and contribute to the community. 
I would add to this question that while clever, questions that can reasonably be answered in multiple ways are generally not well accepted around here. The goal for good puzzle making is to create a clever puzzle that is really only well answered by one true correct answer. Finding the balance of enough information and not too much is the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are:

> A question. Because *What am I?* is a question.

Answer (score 3):

You are

> A riddle.

because

> there's nothing else to go on. Also, you said it yourself: "...in this riddle."

Answer (score 3):

You are:

> Someone
>  Reason: 'I' must be 'someone' from OP's username.

Comment: That would be "who"

Answer (score 3):

You are

> An axe or chainsaw

because

> I am a tree and that would really stump me